Discontinuity in plotting equations in form of powers of $e$ as opposed to trigonometric forms
I have been trying to plot an 2 equations but when I write code to plot those equations in terms of powers or e it shows a discontinuous graph but same equations when simplified in terms of trignometric functions sine and cosine, they plot normally with no discontinuity. I tried to plot these two forms of same equations in python as well and I get same type of discontinuity in powers of e but not in trigonometric equations of same equations
Plot[{E^(-I K1) (4 + 3 E^(I K1) + 4 E^(2 I K1) - Sqrt[
     3 + 4 E^(I K1) + 12 E^(2 I K1) + 4 E^(3 I K1) + 3 E^(4 I K1)]), 
  E^(-I K1) (4 + 3 E^(I K1) + 4 E^(2 I K1) + Sqrt[
     3 + 4 E^(I K1) + 12 E^(2 I K1) + 4 E^(3 I K1) + 
      3 E^(4 I K1)])}, {K1, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotLabel -> Style["\[CapitalGamma]-X Direction, Layer=2"]]

Same equation if I simplify to trignometric form gives a normal continuous function

Plot[{3 + 8 Cos[K1] - Sqrt[8 Cos[K1] + 6 (2 + Cos[2 K1])], 
  3 + 8 Cos[K1] + Sqrt[8 Cos[K1] + 6 (2 + Cos[2 K1])]}, {K1, 0, 2 Pi}]


Please paste copy&pastable code instead of screenshots. It is not fair to the people who are trying to assist to make them need to retype all your content based on some images.

@MariuszIwaniuk My apologies, I've made edits accordingly

The functions in the two plots are not equal. How did you simplify the first set to get the second set?

I simply took one equation and then opened it up by converting powers of e to trignometric function. I've done simplification manually as well as mathematica so I can assure you both functions are same

Please show the code that you used to simplify.

Here's what I get when I take your original expression and apply expr // ExpToTrig // Simplify to it. How did you get rid of the complex terms under the square roots?

The problem is the branch cut in Sqrt[], which is different in the two expressions:
ReImPlot[{
  Sqrt[8 Cos[K1] + 6 (2 + Cos[2 K1])],
  Sqrt[3 + 4 E^(I K1) + 12 E^(2 I K1) + 4 E^(3 I K1) + 
    3 E^(4 I K1)]},
 {K1, 0, 2 Pi}]


Luckily, we can shift the branch cut out of the way (update: found a better shift E^(-2 I K1)):
With[{rt = 
   E^(I K1/2) Sqrt[E^(-2 I K1) (3 + 4 E^(I K1) + 12 E^(2 I K1) + 
        4 E^(3 I K1) + 3 E^(4 I K1))]},
 Plot[{
   E^(-I K1) (4 + 3 E^(I K1) + 4 E^(2 I K1) - rt),
   E^(-I K1) (4 + 3 E^(I K1) + 4 E^(2 I K1) + rt)},
  {K1, 0, 2 Pi}]
 ]



Thanks a lot for your answer, this does solve my issue but I don't understand why this works. Could you elaborate on how you made branch cut go out of way?

Could you also tell a step by step method as to how you got this such that I can apply it to other such equations?

@HarshdeepChhabra The basic idea is that $(c^{-1}\sqrt{c^2b})^2=(\sqrt{b})^2=b$, but $\sqrt{c^2b}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ will have different branch cuts. Now find a $c$ so that the branch cut (negative real axis) is not crossed by $c^2b$. It's not unique, but the first graph shows the argument increasing. So $c^2$ = -E^(-I K1) seemed a good start. It worked so I didn't follow up on the fact that the branch cut is crossed twice, which suggests E^(-2 I K1) is a better choice. I updated my answer. Another way: $c^2=\exp(-i\int_0^{K1} {d \over dt} \arg(z(t)),dt)$, if it can be solved. (It can here!)
